# How can I convert an array of strings to an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-conversion

I have this array:

```
myArray = ["AAA","BBB",...,"ZZZ"];
```

I want to convert it to **an array of objects**. Something like this:

```
myArray = [
    {
        "Id": "111",
        "Value": "AAA"
    },
    ....
    {
        "Id": "111",
        "Value": "ZZZ"
    },
];
```

I've tried to use the **map** method like this:

```
myArray.map(str => {
    let obj = {};
    obj['Id'] = '111';
    obj['Value'] = str;
});
```

**But** `console.log(myArray)` outputs this:

> undefined

Comment: `map` doesn't change the array. It returns a new version of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a result from the mapper function.

```
let myNewArray = myArray.map( str => {
      let obj = {};
      obj['Id'] = '111' ;
      obj['Value'] = str ;
      return obj;
});
// or 
let myNewArray = myArray.map( str =>  ({Id:111,Value:str}) );
// parenthesis are needed to remove the ambiguity with `{}`
console.log(myNewArray);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Using_map_to_reformat_objects_in_an_array

Answer (score 1):

Here is the clean ES6 one liner version using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = myArray = ["AAA","BBB","ZZZ"];

let result = data.map(e => ({'Id': '111', 'Value': e}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result into a new variable, or your existing one, as `map` create a new array and doesn't change the one you are iterating over.

```
    const myArrayOfObjects = myArray.map( str => {
      let obj = {};
      obj['Id'] = '111' ;
      obj['Value'] = str ;
      return obj;
});
```